# Node.js Callback manipulation check

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am writing a scheduling program that returns JSON data about courses. I just started Node.js a week ago so I'm not sure if I'm thinking right.
I am trying to find a better way to write this code and avoid callback hell. I have already written the getJSON method.

```
/*getJSON(course-name, callback(JSONretrieved)): gets JSON info about name and
takes in a callback to manipulate retrieved JSON data*/
```

Now I want to get multiple course-name from a course array and check for time conflicts between them. I will then add all viable combinations to an answer array. My current idea is:

```
/*courseArray: array of classes to be compared
answers: array of all nonconflicting classes*/
var courseArray = ['MATH-123','CHEM-123']
var answers=[]
getJSON(courseArray[0],function(class1data){
    getJSON(courseArray[1],function(class2data){
         if(noConflict) answers.push( merge(class1data,class2data))
     })
    )
  })
);
```

Finally, to access the answer array we wrap the entire code from above:

```
function getAnswers(cb){
    /*courseArray: array of classes to be compared
answers: array of all nonconflicting classes*/
var courseArray = ['MATH-123','CHEM-123']
var answers=[]
getJSON(courseArray[0],function(class1data){
    getJSON(courseArray[1],function(class2data){
         /check for time conflicts between class1data and class2 data
         if(noConflict(class1data,class2data)) answers.push( merge(class1data,class2data))
     })
    )
  })
);
cb(answers)
}
```

and we call the function

```
getAnswers(function(ans){
  //do processing of answers
  console.log(ans)
})
```

My main question is if there is any way to make this code shorter, more readable, or less callback hecky.

Comment: In my opinion callbacks are fine, until they aren't and you're in hell. At that point it's time to learn promises, or use a module like [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird), [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) or [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) etc

Comment: Yup I completely agree. Just transitioning from a synchronous mindset (I am mainly Java and PHP) to async is very jarring and unnatural so I am trying to force myself to learn by writing the callbacks myself. Might be time to use promises though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a promise library to make things easier for yourself. The way you're doing it can quickly get out of hand if the user selects more than a handful of courses to compare.

With something like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async), you can make [parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) calls to `getJSON` and your `conflict` code will run inside a single callback once all of the `getJSON` calls have returned. Your code will be much more readable and maintainable for large arrays of courses.

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely check out async. I've been looking into Bluebird but what turns me away from bluebird is that I need to rewrite my current functions so they can be promisified. Do you think I should choose async over bluebird because of that reason?

Comment: They are both battle-tested and well maintained libraries, so I'd say go with whatever is easiest to integrate with!